# Webpack5-How to execute js file in global scope?

Tags: javascript, webpack-5

I have an old project that use  to load js.

And js file load on global var

such as

`index.html`

```html
<head>
  <script src="Foo.js"></script>
  <script src="Bar.js"></script>
</head>
```

`Foo.js`

```js
var Foo = function(some_var){
   //DO SOMETHING
}
var foo_text = 'HELLO WORLD'
```

`Bar.js`

```js
var result = Foo(foo_text)
```

It works fine

Now I use Webpack to build `Foo.js` and `Bar.js` into one js file,but modules cant execute on Global scope

So it will get `function Foo is undefined` error

This is my `webpack.config.ts`

```js
import path from 'path';
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin';
import { Configuration, IgnorePlugin, ProvidePlugin } from 'webpack';
import { Configuration as DevConfig } from "webpack-dev-server"

const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production';


const config: Configuration & DevConfig = {
    entry: './src/index.ts',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    devServer: {
        open: true,
        host: 'localhost',
    },
    // devtool: false,
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'src/index.html',
        }),
        // ignore require function
        new IgnorePlugin({
            'checkResource': (r, c) => {
                if (c.endsWith('js')) {
                    return true
                }
                return false
            }
        }),
        // new ProvidePlugin({

        // }),
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/i,
                loader: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: ['/node_modules/'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|png|jpg|gif)$/i,
                type: 'asset',
            },
            {
                // include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/js'),

                resourceQuery: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/js'),
                type: 'javascript/auto'
                // type: 'asset'
                // use: []

            }

            // Add your rules for custom modules here
            // Learn more about loaders from https://webpack.js.org/loaders/
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.jsx', '.js', '...']
    },
};

export default () => {
    if (isProduction) {
        config.mode = 'production';


    } else {
        config.mode = 'development';
    }
    return config;
};
```

How to resolve it?

My Project is Webpack 5

i tried `script-loader` ,but repo not support now

Many variables are defined in `Foo.js`, so I can't export them all

`Foo.js` and `Bar.js` on single file and Foo is in global var

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: CacheMap is not defined
    <anonymous> webpack://my-webpack-project/./src/js/rpg_managers.js?:794
    js http://localhost:8080/main.js:400
    __webpack_require__ http://localhost:8080/main.js:469
    fn http://localhost:8080/main.js:681
    <anonymous> webpack://my-webpack-project/./src/index.ts?:11
    ts http://localhost:8080/main.js:85
    __webpack_require__ http://localhost:8080/main.js:469
    <anonymous> http://localhost:8080/main.js:1557
    <anonymous> http://localhost:8080/main.js:1559
```